# Get images from wordpress post with json in windows phone

Tags: json, wordpress, windows-phone-7, post

I would like to get Images from a wordpress Blog. I would start only with one post not with all the posts images.

I am using this code. It works to get the title, excerpt, url... But I cant get images :

namespace WpWordpressJson
{

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string SampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _sampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _sampleProperty)
            {
                _sampleProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadData()
    {
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://automaticband.es/bio/", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://automaticband.es/bio/?json=get_recent_posts");
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        downloader.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(downloader_OpenReadCompleted);
        downloader.OpenReadAsync(serviceUri);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    void downloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream responseStream = e.Result;
                DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Posts));
                Posts response = (Posts)ser.ReadObject(responseStream);
                if (response.posts != null && response.posts.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Post post in response.posts)
                    {
                        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = post.title, LineTwo = post.excerpt });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Post
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id;
    [DataMember]
    public string type;
    [DataMember]
    public string slug;
    [DataMember]
    public string title;
    [DataMember]
    public string content;
    [DataMember]
    public string excerpt;
}

[DataContract]
public class Posts
{
    [DataMember]
    public int count;
    [DataMember]
    public int count_total;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Post> posts;
}
```

I got it from this site:

http://kevinashley.com/connect-windows-phone-7-apps-to-wordpress-using-json/

Thank you for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the DataMember for thumbnails in Post. Here you can find a full class for WordPress JSON API: http://msicc.net/?p=2929
Hope this helps :-)